# multiprocessing.Process.is_alive() returns True although process has finished, why?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I use `multiprocess.Process` to create a child process and then call `os.wait4` until child exists. When the actual child process finishes, `multiprocess.Process.is_alive()` still returns `True`. That's contradicting. Why?

Code:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
import os, sys

proc = Process(target=os.system, args= ("sleep 2", ))
proc.start()

print "is_alive()", proc.is_alive()
ret = os.wait4(proc.pid, 0)
procPid, procStatus, procRes = ret
print "wait4 = ", ret

## Puzzled!
print "----Puzzled below----"
print "is_alive()", proc.is_alive()
if os.WIFEXITED(procStatus):
    print "exit with status", os.WEXITSTATUS(procStatus)
print "is_alive()", proc.is_alive()
sys.exit(1)
```

Output:

```
is_alive() True
wait4 =  (11137, 0, resource.struct_rusage(ru_utime=0.0028959999999999997, ru_stime=0.003189, ru_maxrss=1363968, ru_ixrss=0, ru_idrss=0, ru_isrss=0, ru_minflt=818, ru_majflt=0, ru_nswap=0, ru_inblock=0, ru_oublock=0, ru_msgsnd=0, ru_msgrcv=0, ru_nsignals=0, ru_nvcsw=1, ru_nivcsw=9))
----Puzzled below----
is_alive() True
exit with status 0
is_alive() True
```

My question is about the last three output lines. Why `is_alive()` return `True` when the actual process is finished. How can that happen?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should use [`Process.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join) instead of `os.wait4`.

- `Process.is_alive` calls `waitpid` internally through `multiprocessing.forking.Popen.poll`.
- If you call `os.wait4`, `waitpid` raises `os.error` which cause the `poll()` to return `None`. (http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c167ab1c49c9/Lib/multiprocessing/forking.py#l141)
- `is_alive()` use that return value to determine whether the process is alive. (http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c167ab1c49c9/Lib/multiprocessing/process.py#l159)

  - => return `True`.

http://asciinema.org/a/5901

---

Replace following line:

```
ret = os.wait4(proc.pid, 0)
```

with:

```
proc.join()
```

Comment: Just to be concrete, the OP should replace the `ret = os.wait4(...` line with `proc.join()`.

Comment: @TimPeters, I added that to the answer. Thank you for comment.

Comment: @falsetru Thanks for your answer. Your asciinema link teaches me very useful Python debug technique. My intention of this question is to get resource of child process from `waitpid`, but it looks like I should bypass multiprocessing.Process in this case.

Comment: What happens if I use process.termninate() to kill a process? Even after terminating, process.is_alive() returns True. Any fix/workaround?

Comment: @Explorer, `terminate`, not `termninate`. According to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate), it send SIGTERM signal on UNIX, call `TerminateProcess()` on windows.

Comment: @Explorer, Maybe the subprocess catch SIGTERM or ignore it. Check how the subprocess handle the signal.